# Sugar ORM just won't create tables

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-testing, sugarorm

I am working on a standalone library project that requires persisting a simple model. Here is what my `SugarRecord` looks like:

```
/**
 *  Keeping track of previously received messages by ID
 */

public class MessageRequestIdModel extends SugarRecord {

    protected String messageRequestId;

    public MessageRequestIdModel() {

    }

    public MessageRequestIdModel(String messageRequestId) {
        this.messageRequestId = messageRequestId;
    }

    public String getMessageRequestId() {
        return this.messageRequestId;
    }

    public static boolean exists(String id) {
        return MessageRequestIdModel.find(
                MessageRequestIdModel.class,
                "messageRequestId = ?",
                id
        ).size() != 0;
    }
}
```

In a repository class, I am attempting to persist it by calling this method:

```
@Override
public void save(MessageRequestId messageRequestId) {
    new MessageRequestIdModel(messageRequestId.getId()).save();
}
```

I now attempt to test this by using an `android.test.InstrumentationTestCase` where I pass a `Context` to Sugar like so:

```
SugarContext.init(getInstrumentation().getContext());
```

This results in this error when I run the test:
(truncating to keep this question a succinct read)

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MESSAGE_REQUEST_ID_MODEL (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT or REPLACE...
```

### Troubleshooting I've already attempted:

- Keeping a different Manifest for the test package to pass the `.test` package name to SugarORM. No change in behaviour
- Adding a `MessageRequestIdModel.findById(MessageRequestIdModel.class, (long) 1);` like in the other SO posts. Changes error to itself (Showing full stack-trace here in case it helps):

  ```
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MESSAGE_REQUEST_ID_MODEL (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM MESSAGE_REQUEST_ID_MODEL WHERE id=? LIMIT 1

  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1240)
  at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:192)
  at com.orm.SugarRecord.findById(SugarRecord.java:102)
  at pm.tin.apprise.entities.message_request_ids.MessageRequestIdModelRepository.save(MessageRequestIdModelRepository.java:19)
  ```
- I've tried removing all Sugar ORM config from the Manifest like suggested by many - this changes nothing
- I've tried creating a Sample App module and tried running it as a test-case for that app, in case Standalone apps didn't get the right resources on the emulator/device (I've tested on both)
- I've tried incrementing the `VERSION` number for the database
- I've tried switching to an `ActivityTestCase` and using `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`. This essentially fails with an error that suggests that this Context is incomplete to be able to setup SQLite

As you can see, I have pushed hard at this boulder all night long, but at this point it is seeming Sisyphean and I have absolutely no lead for my next debug attempt other than to use a different ORM than Sugar (which doesn't really seem to be the problem). There is nothing more emasculating that not being able to run SQLite in a Test Case and I cry to the Holy Programmer Consciousness in you for help :-'(

Comment: What version of Android Studio were you using? It may be related to the [following issue](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/536)

Comment: @EdGeorge seems like it very much yes!

Comment: Then I will add it as an answer :)

Comment: @EdGeorge I am however on Gradle 1.5.0 :( It certainly might help somebody though yes - will follow this issue and if this fixes it switch as accepted answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should conclusively solve this problem for all the folks out there struggling to get Sugar ORM to work out of the box - *use the SQL versioning system to manually fire creation SQL.*

In the above use-case, here is how you do it:

1.) Change Sugar ORM config's DB version to a new number (say `N`) such that it is greater than the current version *OR* change database name

2.) Create a file `ModuleName/src/main/assets/sugar_upgrades/<N>.sql` with your SQL; showing mine, in case it helps:

> DROP TABLE MESSAGE_REQUEST_ID_MODEL;
>
> CREATE TABLE MESSAGE_REQUEST_ID_MODEL(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MESSAGE_REQUEST_ID CHAR(128));

This will force Sugar to fire your SQL to create the table for you (albeit manually).

**Additional Notes**

- This section of the Sugar ORM manual is the inspiration behind this (albeit hacky) fix: http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html
- I have commented out the package name from Sugar config
- Sugar works with an Instrumentation Application Context. In a base class of `InstrumentationTestCase`, simply do `SugarContext.init(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext())` as shown in the original question

Comment: You helped me man, this was the solution to my problem, Thank you :)

Answer (score 23):

This issue has been observed in Android Studio 2.x.x-beta versions (most notably 2.0.0-beta6) and has its root cause in the 'Instant Run' feature.

I imagine this may be fixed shortly, but for this to work in the meantime, you should disable the feature in the following menu

`File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Instant Run`

Cleaning and then building the application should resolve these issues.

You can see the related Sugar bug report [here](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/536).

Comment: This is now fixed and in the master branch. See https://github.com/satyan/sugar/pull/564 it's not yet in an official release, but `compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:b16e65326a'` has the fix  (this uses jitpack)

Comment: Got AS 2.3.1 and using the latest sugar .. still the same error :(

Comment: I have instant run disabled and I'm getting the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

**your problem may be creation of class...**

```
public class MessageRequestIdModel extends SugarRecord<MessageRequestIdModel> {

    protected String messageRequestId;

    public MessageRequestIdModel() {

    }

    public MessageRequestIdModel(String messageRequestId) {
        this.messageRequestId = messageRequestId;
    }

    public String getMessageRequestId() {
        return this.messageRequestId;
    }

    public static boolean exists(String id) {
        return MessageRequestIdModel.find(
                MessageRequestIdModel.class,
                "messageRequestId = ?",
                id
        ).size() != 0;
    }
}
```

please recheck with my code.

Comment: Your syntax is for Sugar ORM 1.3, whereas I am on Sugar ORM 1.4. In 1.4, `SugarRecord` has no Generic Type Parameter, which means this won't even compile for me.

Comment: OK. thanks for suggest me.  you can increase version of Suger ORM by manifest and run once again.